# Half edge twins

Tags: c++, data-structures

I have implemented a Half-edge data structure for loading 3d objects. I find that the part of assigning twin/pair edges takes the longest computation time (especially for objects which have hundreds of thousands half edges). The reason is that I use nested loops to accomplish this. Is there a simpler and efficient way of doing this?
Below is the code which I've written. HE is the half-edge data structure. hearr is a vector containing all the half edges. vert is the starting vertex and end is the ending vertex. Thanks!!

```
HE *e1,*e2;

for(size_t i=0;i<hearr.size();i++){
    e1=hearr[i];
    for(size_t j=1;j<hearr.size();j++){
        e2=hearr[j];
        if((e1->vert==e2->end)&&(e2->vert==e1->end)){
            e1->twin=e2;
            e2->twin=e1;
        }
    }
}
```

I used some simple keywords like break and continue, and also set the value of j in the inner loop as j=i. This improved the speed significantly. Earlier it took my 403 seconds for a set of data. Now its 11 seconds. These are the changes. Any comments are welcome. Thanks!

```
for(size_t i=0;i<hearr.size();i++){
    e1=hearr[i];
    if(e1->twin!=0)
        continue;

        for(size_t j=i;j<hearr.size();j++){
            e2=hearr[j];
            if(e2->twin!=0)
                continue;
            if((e1->vert==e2->end)&&(e2->vert==e1->end)){
                e1->twin=e2;
                e2->twin=e1;
                break;
            }
        }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution.  I haven't compiled it.

The basic idea is to sort the range by (vert then end) and by (end then vert).  Each of these takes nlgn time.

We then walk both lists in parallel looking for ranges where the vert-major sorted list's end equals the end-major sorted list's end.

One we have these ranges, we call `DoTwins`.  This walks the ranges in question, looking for where the vert-major list's end matches the end-major list's vert.  I then check if there are multiple edges that are exactly equivalent (if there are, things go poorly, so I assert), then hook up the twins.

Each iteration of each loop (inner or outer) advances where we are analyzing in a list by 1, and each outer loop never looks back.  So this is O(n).

Note that the `DoTwins` loop and the loop that calls `DoTwins` follow basically the same logic with slightly different tests.  Refactoring that logic might improve the code.

Disclaimer: Code has not been compiled (or run, or debugged), just written from scratch, so expect there to be typos and errors.  But the basic idea should be sound.

```
// A procedure to solve a subproblem -- the actual assignment of the
// twin variables.  The left range's "vert" field should equal the
// right range's "end" field before you call this function.  It proceeds
// to find the subsets where the left "end" equals the right "vert",
// and sets their twin field to point to each other.  Note that things
// go squirrly if there are multiple identical edges.
template< typename HEPtrRange >
void DoTwins( HEPtrRange EqualVertRange, HEPtrRange EqualEndRange )
{
  auto it1 = EqualVertRange.first;
  auto it2 = EqualEndRange.first;
  while( it1 != EqualVertRange.second && it2 != EqualEndRange.second )
  {
    Assert((*it1)->vert == (*it2)->end);
    if ((*it1)->end > (*it2)->vert)
    {
      ++(*it2);
      continue;
    }
    if ((*it1)->end < (*it2)->vert)
    {
      ++(*it1);
      continue;
    }
    Assert((*it1)->end == (*it2)->vert);
    // sanity check for multiple identical edges!
    auto it3 = it1;
    while (it3 != EqualVertRange.second && (*it3)->end == (*it1)->end)
      ++it3;
    auto it4 = it2;
    while (it4 != EqualVertRange.second && (*it4)->end == (*it2)->end)
      ++it4;
    // the range [it1, it3) should have its twin set to the elements
    // in the range [it2, it4).  This is impossible unless they
    // are both of size one:
    Assert( it3 - it1 == 1 );
    Assert( it4 - it2 == 1 );
    for (auto it = it1; it != it3; ++it)
      (*it)->twin = it2;
    for (auto it = it2; it != it4; ++it)
      (*it)->twin = it1;
    it1 = it3;
    it2 = it4;
  }
}
```

Elsewhere:

```
// A vector of the edges sorted first by vert, then by end:
std::vector<HE*> vertSorted(&hearr[0], (&hearr[0]).size());
std::sort(vertSorted.begin(), vertSorted.end(),
  [](HE* e1, HE* e2)
  {
    if (e1->vert != e2->vert)
      return e1->vert < e2->vert;
    return e1->end < e2->end;
  }
);
// A vector of the edges sorted first by end, then by vert:
std::vector<HE*> endSorted = vertSorted;
std::sort(endSorted.begin(), endSorted.end(),
  [](HE* e1, HE* e2)
  {
    if (e1->end != e2->end)
      return e1->end < e2->end;
    return e1->vert < e2->vert;
  }
);

// iterate over both at the same time:
auto it1 = vertSorted.begin();
auto it2 = endSorted.begin();
while(it1 != vertSorted.end() && it2 != endSorted.end())
{
  // we are looking for cases where left->vert == right->end.
  // advance the one that is "lagging behind":
  if ((*it1)->vert > (*it2)->end)
  {
    ++it2;
    continue;
  }
  if ((*it1)->vert < (*it2)->end)
  {
    ++it1;
    continue;
  }
  Assert( (*it1)->vert == (*it2)->end );
  // Find the end of the range where left->vert == right->end
  auto it3 = it1;
  while (it3 != vertSorted.end() && (*it3)->vert == (*it1)->vert)
  {
    ++it3;
  }
  auto it4 = it2;
  while (it4 != endSorted.end() && (*it4)->vert == (*it2)->vert)
  {
    ++it4;
  }
  auto EqualVertRange = std::make_pair(it1, it3);
  auto EqualEndRange = std::make_pair(it2, it4);
  // Delegate reverse lookups and assignment of twin variable to a subprocedure:
  DoTwins( EqualVertRange, EqualEndRange );
  it1 = it3;
  it2 = it4;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the code and detailed comments! I will try out your approach.

Answer (score 0):

A better solution would be to sort the array, then perform a binary search providing your own comparison. Or consider hashing each node, then performing a lookup while providing a custom comparison

Comment: I thought of binary search too. Thanks! I'll try and let you know how it goes.